# Preload JSON XHR request using a link tag

Tags: html, xmlhttprequest, fetch, preload

I want to preload JSON (using `<link rel="preload" ...>`) that will be requested by my application later on via an XHR request (axios).

So far I got it working in Chrome by using the following link tag:

```html
<link rel="preload" href="https://swapi.dev/api/people/1" as="fetch" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And later on executing the following axios request:

```js
axios.get("https://swapi.dev/api/people/1", {
  headers: {
    accept: "*/*"
  }
})
```

The dev tools reveal only one request, as expected.

Safari however, requests the JSON a second time. I made sure the request headers are identical. What am I doing wrong?

I made a reduced test case on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/JorenVanHee/pen/PoXogmo?editors=1010).

---

The test case also contains a button to fire a request using `fetch`. So far I have tested it in Chrome, Safari and Firefox. Here are my results:

| Browser | XHR | fetch |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chrome | ✅ | ✅ |
| Firefox | ❌ | ✅ |
| Safari | ❌ | ❌ |